# Beginner: Need to find better way to get something done

Tags: python

I am working out of the Learn Python the Hard Way book and I have a very beginner question. I am trying to get it so that the code below does not have to go through such a weird way to check if a number was given, also, I want numbers that don't have 1 or 0 to be valid.

```
def gold_room():
    print("The room is full of gold, how much do you take?")

    choice = raw_input("> ")
    if "0" in choice or "1" in choice:
        how_much = int(choice)
```

The idea that I had was to get it to check if choice was an integer, and if so then trigger the code, but I can not figure out how to do this. I am sure the answer is very simple, and I'm sorry for such a basic question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf NO Do NOT use `eval` on strings from `raw_input`. That is a terrible habit. Use the string method `.isdigit`

Comment: As a side note, why not combine the first two lines: `choice = raw_input("The room is full of gold, how much do you take? ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking only for non-negative integers, than `choice.isdigit()` will suffice. It returns `True` or `False`, depending on whether `choice` consists of all digits or not. Complete solution:

```
def gold_room():
  choice = raw_input("The room is full of gold, how much do you take? ")
  if choice.isdigit():
    return int(choice)
  else:
    return None
```

Comment: So with this would I be able to do `choice = raw_input("> " )` and then `if choice.isdigit() = True: ` `how_much = choice` ? Thank you

Comment: @MagicalMan, you still need to convert `choice` to an int: `how_much=int(choice)`.

Comment: So for some reason if I do `choice = raw_input("> ")` `if choice.isdigit() = True:` `how_much = int(choice)` I am getting a syntx error on `if choice.isdigit() = True:` Do you know why? Sorry for all of the questions.

Comment: You must use `==`, not `=` when checking for equality (that's why: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-and-in-Python-2)

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh well, I feel stupid now. I didn't think of it seeing if the two things were equal in that sense I was thinking about saying if choice was true. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use, also, `try .. accept` and catch the error.
You can follow this example:

```
def gold_room():
    print("The room is full of gold, how much do you take?")

    choice = raw_input("> ")
    try:
        return int(choice)
    except ValueError:
        pass

print gold_room()
```

Output:

if for example the input was 12

```
>> 12
```

if the input isn't an integer so the output will be `None`:

```
>> None
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I will use .isdigit but one thing I noticed was that in your code it still only will take numbers with 0 or 1 so something like 23 will not work. Do you know how to avoid that? Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: If `choice` is not an integer, `int(choice)` throws an exception even before `isinstance()` kicks in. There is no point in calling it.

Comment: @MagicalMan, if so you can remove `if "0" in choice or "1" in choice:` i added it only because you wrote it in your question.

Comment: @DYZ this is why i used `try ... except` to catch the exception which is a `ValueError`.

Comment: Ah. Thank you I don't understand what the except is, I have not learned it yet in my book but I am sure I will learn about it soon.

Comment: @nexus66 My point is that whether you use `isinstance()` or not, you will get exactly the same result. Line #6 can be removed from your example, and it will still work.

Comment: @MagicalMan Yes. Go ahead and don't hesitate to update your question if you have any others. Have fun ;)

Comment: @nexus66: What DYZ means is that `int` always returns an integer. `isinstance(int(...), int)` always either throws because of the `int` call (which you catch), or returns True. It is useless in that situation

Comment: @3Doubloons thank you, I mostly understand what is going on now.

Comment: @3Doubloons `int(x)` either returns an int or throws an exception.